# If web browser user modifies Javascript and executes it (e.g. from console), does it violate same-origin policy?

Tags: javascript, html

For example: Server renders a page and then user makes an Ajax call using Javascript console to the same host using same protocol. Does it violate same-origin policy?

Follow up question - if the above scenario does not violate same-origin policy, is there any way to make sure that web browser is executing genuine, unmodified Javascript from my host?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and No. It is not possible to know if the user changes the code. I do not even need a console. I can hijack the http responses and serve different files. That is why you need to validate everything on the server.